# Debugging Gradle task won't stop on a breakpoint

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, breakpoints, remote-debugging

I'm developing a new Gradle task and would like to use debugger.

My Gradle task looks like this

```
task listMissingDependencies {
    group = 'other'
    doLast {
        println "Put breakpoint here"
    }
}
```

I put a breakpoint in the line with println.

First I start Gradle task in debug mode by running

```
./gradlew listMissingDependencies --stacktrace -Dorg.gradle.debug=true --no-daemon -Dorg.gradle.debug=true
```

And prints this message

```
To honour the JVM settings for this build a single-use Daemon process will be forked. See https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#sec:disabling_the_daemon.
Daemon will be stopped at the end of the build
```

Server starts on port 5005 and I connect by Intellij using this configuration
[image: Intellij configuration]

Then the task is executed and I get it's output.

```
> Task :listMissingDependencies
Put breakpoint here

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1m 58s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
```

Why doesn't Intellij stop on a breakpoint?

Gradle 7.5.1

JVM 17.0.2 (Oracle Corporation 17.0.2+8-LTS-86)

IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1.2 (Ultimate Edition)

Comment: Seems you are running your Task using raw Gradle.
Try creating a Run/Debug Config in IDEA:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-gradle.html
Some more details on Gradle Debug in IDEA:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/work-with-gradle-tasks.html#control_debug
and for debugging Gradle Tasksspecifically:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/work-with-gradle-tasks.html#debug_script